# "Could not find or load main class Online" error when running tests from TeamCity

Tags: java, teamcity

I am initiating some Selenium tests from a TeamCity build. These tests run fine when I run them from comand with `mvn test` for example. But when running through Teamity we get the error message "Could not find or load main class Online".

From reaidng various articles with similar error I was thinking it's to do with Classpath so I made some changes to my system variables but problem persists.

I have put below my various system variables and also my project structure if this helps.

I'm a bit confused by the error message which states a class of 'Online' but I dont have a class called this in my project.

```
CLASSPATH = .;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4
JDK_HOME = %JAVA_HOME%
JRE_HOME = C:\TeamCity\jre
Path = C:\Projects\BDD\MDA Online Framework\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;other path stuff here
```

Project structure:

```
MDA Online Framework
├───.idea
│   ├───dictionaries
│   └───libraries
├───Maven
│   └───apache-maven-3.5.4
│       ├───bin
│       ├───boot
│       ├───conf
│       │   └───logging
│       └───lib
│           ├───ext
│           └───jansi-native
│               ├───freebsd32
│               ├───freebsd64
│               ├───linux32
│               ├───linux64
│               ├───osx
│               ├───windows32
│               └───windows64
├───Reporting
│   ├───ADAWA
│   ├───DPL
│   ├───MOP
│   ├───MOS
│   ├───OA
│   ├───TPOS
│   └───wikipedia.html
├───run
├───Selenium
│   └───libs
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   ├───java
│   │   └───resources
│   └───test
│       ├───java
│       │   ├───config
│       │   ├───Database
│       │   ├───Pages
│       │   └───stepdefs
│       │       ├───MOPStepDefs
│       │       ├───MOSStepDefs
│       │       ├───OAStepDefs
│       │       └───TPOSStepDefs
│       └───Resources
│           ├───MOP Features
│           ├───MOS Features
│           ├───Online Apps
│           └───TPOS
└───target
    ├───classes
    ├───generated-sources
    │   └───annotations
    ├───generated-test-sources
    │   └───test-annotations
    ├───maven-status
    │   └───maven-compiler-plugin
    │       ├───compile
    │       │   └───default-compile
    │       └───testCompile
    │           └───default-testCompile
    ├───surefire-reports
    └───test-classes
        ├───config
        ├───Database
        ├───MOP Features
        ├───MOS Features
        ├───Online Apps
        ├───Pages
        ├───stepdefs
        │   ├───MOPStepDefs
        │   ├───MOSStepDefs
        │   ├───OAStepDefs
        │   └───TPOSStepDefs
        └───TPOS
```

Comment: Online is a part of the path to maven and it contains spaces... i'm sure error linked to that.

Comment: you should compile before the test. try `mvn clean install test`

Comment: Thanks @daggett My project folder is called 'MDA Online Framework' if this helps. Are you saying this cant contain spaces? I've updated the tree in my original post.

Comment: @daggett I found the problem and you were right about spaces. I put in some quote marks around that now and it works. Thanks a lot.Put this as an answer if you like and I can mark it as correct.